# Remove the top and bottom layout guides in interface builder

Tags: xcode, autolayout, interface-builder

I'd like to do autolayout based on the parent view, but the top and bottom layout guides are fighting me. Thing is, I'm in an embedded view controller and they aren't relevant:

[image]

The layout guides are here:

[image]

I thought maybe one of these settings would remove them, but no luck:

[image]

How do I get rid of these guides? If that's not possible, any info on why they get created would be really helpful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 21):

Remove the top and bottom layout guides pic

[image]

Comment: I had to deselect and reselect `Use Safe Area Layout Guides` to remove the Top/Bottom layout guides and still keep safe area layout guides.

Comment: Those options aren't available anywhere for me.  I've inherited a project with .xib files btw.

Answer (score 11):

Simply to deselect and reselect `Use Safe Area Layout Guides`,
as Apple deprecated `Top Layout Guide`

@Daniel Storm's answer is more accurate.

@Juan's answer is good , not very ok.

[image: 1]
[image: 3]

[image: 2]

Comment: Thanks at @Alsh compiler's editing. My hand shakes.

Answer (score 6):

Autolayout is using an inferred status bar size.

To change this, select the view controller, and show the Attributes Inspector. Change the Status Bar attribute from Inferred (as shown in your question) to None.

Comment: I can't recall, but it looks like from my question I'm saying that I tried fiddling all the knobs in that screenshot and setting Status Bar: none did not remove the layout guides. Maybe this was a bug and was fixed in a later xcode version.

You are saying that setting it to none definitely should remove the top and bottom layout guides?

Comment: I just made a blank VC and set Status Bar: None. It does not remove the top and bottom layout guides. Xcode v8.0 (8A218a)

Comment: In your blank VC, did you also set Top & Bottom Bar to none? Maybe you need to also

Comment: Maybe you also need to hide the Status bar, by setting Status Bar Is Initially Hidden = YES and View Controller-based Status Bar Appearance = NO.

Comment: I just created a brand new project and was able to remove the guides. (1) I selected the View Controller and set Status Bar, Top Bar, Bottom Bar to None. (2) I added an UIImageView to the main view, and created four constraints to leading, trailing, top & bottom. (3) I hid the Status bar by setting Status Bar Is Initially Hidden = YES and View Controller-based Status Bar Appearance = NO.

Comment: However, I still had margins on the left & right. The leading & trailing constrains are relative to margin by default. So, (4) In the constraint editor, I unchecked "Relative to margin" from the Superview.trailing and Superview.leading items.  The project is online at [link](http://blackfrog.com/NoGuide/NoGuide.zip)

Comment: Sorry, for some reason I can't edit my comments. I meant to say, the project is online at [http://blackfrog.com/NoGuide/NoGuide.zip](http://blackfrog.com/NoGuide/NoGuide.zip)

Comment: `View Controller-based Status Bar Appearance` is a project wide setting. I can't change that just to get this VC to work. Is it necessary?

Comment: I don't know. You'll have to experiment. My guess is that you can achieve the same effect when the active view controller is managing the status bar appearance.

Comment: None of this worked for me.  I've inherited .xib files in this project.  Still trying to find way to remove Top and Bottom Layout Guide.

Answer (score 0):

You have to manually do that in the `storyboard`. Start selecting and seeing from the top view to the inner ones and find the `view` that has some visually top and bottom margin given automatically by the `layout guide`.

When you find the view modify the "`Bottom`" and "`Top`" `constraint` to be against "`Superview`" instead of "`Bottom Layout guide`" or "`Top Layout guide`" and don't forget to give it a `constant` of `0` instead of 20/-20 that could be applied automatically.